# NiFi MergeContent not doing processing flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

I have several Nifi flows consuming data from Kafka then writing it on HDFS. Before writing on HDFS, we use `MergeContent` to merge flowfiles and write bigger messages (sort of like a batch).

For 2 of those flows however, `MergeContent` doesn't seem to process flowfiles : flowfiles stay stuck in the queue before `MergeContent` processor. I've tried modifying the `Max Bin Age` parameter, as well as the Maximum  and Minimum Number of Entries, it doesn't change anything. Flowfiles stay in the queue far beyond the `max bin age` period.

Here are screenshots of the `MergeContent` properties :

[image: Merge Content Properties]

[image: Merge Content Scheduling Properties]

Here is also a screenshot of the queue. You can see nothing has been processed for at least the last 5 minutes. You can also see that some flowfiles did get merged, the flow was working fine when I first started it, the problem appeared after 10 minutes or so.

[image: Nifi queue]

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Do all of the MergeContent processors use a Correlation Attribute or only the ones that are not merging?

Comment: All of them use a Correlation Attribute